# how to put text below image in ionic framework , in footer section

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am asking this question again, because my previous question is not clear. I am going to draw a screen, in ionic framework, where in the footer section, I want to create the same thing which is attached as image. I have tried the below code, no text is coming below picture

[footer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6DDE.png)

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">
<button class="button button-icon">
<i class="icon ion-plus"></i> 
<p>styles</p>
</button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ion-tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/) it is very simple... to use custom icon refer to this [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-custom-icons-with-tabs-0-9-26/1628)

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <!-- Tab 1 content -->
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
    <!-- Tab 2 content -->
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
    <!-- Tab 3 content -->
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```